# Save values to an array permanently?

Tags: php

Is there a way to store values that I append to an array for further cases?
For example, I create an array in one page of php and from another page I append value to the array on the first page. The problem appears when the second page tries to append another value to first page and the value gets replaced. I shall explain with code.

FirstPage.php

```
<?php
global $file;
print_r ($file);
?>
```

SecondPage.php

```
<?php
$file = array();
$id=$_GET['id'];
array_push($file, "$id"); //ID = 1 here
include('FirstPage.php');
?>
```

When I execute the SecondPage.php, the output is

```
Array ( [0] => 1)
```

Then I change the value of ID = 2, the output then is

```
Array ( [0] => 2)
```

So the values never get stored in FirstPage.php, they always get replaced.

Comment: Use a session variable.

Comment: If you want to retain data across multiple pages, then using a database is the most common solution (unless it is very localised when a user session is more appropriate).

Comment: Store it in a database and retrieve it every time you need it!

Comment: I thought of Database but then I will be performing alot of operations, such as insertion and clearing of arrays so i thought it would not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *session variable* for this by assigning the value to the session variable on the first page as

**SESSION**

*First Page*

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['variable'] = $file; //variable assigned the value of array()
print_r ($file);
?>
```

And on the second page assign the value session variable to the simple variable.

*Second Page*

```
<?php
session_start();
$file = $_SESSION['variable'];
$id=$_GET['id'];
array_push($file, $id); //ID = 1 here
?>
```

And after this you don't need to include first page in again.

As you have not mentioned your `array()` in the question take this as an example

**First.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$file = $_SESSION['varname'];
print_r($file);
?>
```

**Second.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$file  = array(1,2,3,4);
array_push($file,'5');
$_SESSION['varname'] = $file;
header("Location: first.php");
?>
```

Comment: Should I not declare file as array in Second Page?

Comment: No there's no need to do it the session variable caries the value of the `$file` to the next page.

Comment: I tried your solution but the value still is getting replaced. That is only index [0] is shown that is always getting replaced.

Comment: you must have assigned the empty array again in the second page as `$file = array();` don't do this.

Comment: Actually the second page is where i will be executing the array first and the first page is only to store and print. Could you please change your script that way? I am getting confused.

Comment: And to get the value of `id` as `2` don't use `"id"` it will print id as in letters use `$id` instead.

Comment: And if i execute FirstPage.php after executing SecondPage.php, I get these errors: ```Notice: Undefined variable: file in /storage/ssd3/779/12780779/public_html/FirstPage.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined variable: file in /storage/ssd3/779/12780779/public_html/FirstPage.php on line 4```

Comment: on the first page you must assign the array to the `$file` as i have mentioned in my answer(commented) i could not guide you through that way because you haven't mentioned it in you question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212681/discussion-between-kunal-raut-and-saif).

Comment: I ended up using database. It was better since the value gets stored permanently.

Comment: Ok if you think so.:)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **database**, save your array to file or use another method of storing data. These operations you are using are stateless. Content of arrays will not be saved between next executions of PHP scripts.

Sessions work until browser closing so it's not also the solution of your problem.

Comment: Yes I ended up using database itself.